# ClosedXML missing formulas and format for new rows after saving

Tags: closedxml

I have an issue that is quite hard to understand, I'm going to try to explain that:

- I have a template xlsx file;
- There are some plans on this workbook and a table for each one;
- Some columns have formulas and specific formats (colors, time, currency and so one);
- If I open directly this template file and insert a new row in any table, things are going well (formulas and formats are being copied for this new row);
- However, if I use Closedxml to open it and saving then, even not manipulating anything, when I open the file using Excel and add a new row to some table this new row is coming with no formulas and formats.

I have no idea what's going on and how to fix it but it's invalidating a requirement because I need to open the template, fill some tables and send to the user for download.

ClosedXML version: 0.87.0.0

Example and template file on: https://github.com/ClosedXML/ClosedXML/issues/513

Comment: Auto-populating tables' formulas has not been implemented in ClosedXML. For now, you'll have to manually copy the formulas into the new cells.

Comment: The issue is not copying when I'm creating the new rows using ClosedXML,  I can create the formulas into the new cells at code time, but the issue is when user are on the excel file and create a new row into a table the the formulas and formats are not being included into cells of this new row as default behavior of a file that I didn't save using ClosedXML.

Comment: Ah ok, I understand now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue has been fixed on the github issue 513:

https://github.com/ClosedXML/ClosedXML/issues/513

Only need to wait the release of this fix.

Comment: This fix has been released on version 0.91.0 https://www.nuget.org/packages/ClosedXML/0.91.0